# How to redirect from front end to expression engine Admin panel

Tags: login, admin, admin.php

I tried login from front end and redirect it to adminpanel but it doesnot logged in  to it. This is the code i tried.

{exp:member:login_form return="www.sample.com/admin.php?/cp/homepage"}

Username

Password

{/exp:member:login_form}

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, logging into the front end will not log you into the EE control panel. You must re-login at admin.php

Comment: This is done for security reasons. And in general it's probably best to actually hide/obfuscate the admin panel login page, and give it a discreet link somewhere.